# PCF8574 I2C Address Selector

Tags: switches, i2c

I'd like to use the [PCF8574](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcf8574.pdf) I/O Expander in a design, however I'd like the I2C address to be set in the field. Since the datasheet specifies that A0-2 should be connected directly VDD or VSS and that no pull-up is required, can I use the following circuit to physically select the address?

[image: Proposed Circuit]

Edit: So based on the comments, A0-2 *may* have internal pull-up resistors. If that's the case, the circuit could be simplified to this:

[image: Simplified Circuit]

Comment: Sure, but because the lines A0, A1, A2 are pulled up internally, your switches should go to GND instead and the resistors are unneeded.

Comment: Just wondering, @Joey, why does your schematic not connect the switches directly to IC1? Net lists are fine for a PCB auto-router but having to search for the other end(s) of each net is much more difficult than following a line. There is also always the fear that it goes somewhere else too.

Comment: Good question, @Transistor! I don’t really have a good answer. I guess it was a matter of personal preference, as I’m new to circuit design. But I’ll take that feedback into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet is rather vague on the subject, but it *appears* that the A0-A2 lines have internal pullups.

If this is really true, then connect your switches between the address lines and ground.  A closed switch forces the line low, and a open switch allows it to float high due to the internal pullup.

You might want to send email to your local TI field application engineer and ask for clarification on whether these inputs really have internal pullups or not.  The wording around that in the datasheet is quite poor, and it wouldn't hurt for the FAE to bring this back to the factory to have it fixed.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts! Unfortunately I'm not an EE (I just play one on the weekends), so I don't have any TI contacts. I'll poke around and see if there's another way to get clarification.

Comment: Oh and Olin commented on my first post on the EE StackExchange! Crazy because I just started designing around PICs and your name comes up everywhere. Thanks for all your work (and making it public)!

Comment: In NXP datasheet we can read " To conserve power, no internal pull-up resistors are incorporated on A2, A1 or A0, so they must be externally held HIGH or LOW. The address pins (A2, A1, A0) can connect to VDD or VSS directly or through resistors "

Comment: Indeed it does. In that case does the original circuit work as intended? Or is there a better design?

Comment: @G36: The OP is using a TI part, and linked to the TI datasheet. I scanned that datasheet and didn't find a similar passage.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Another question, when manufacturers share part numbers, are the internal designs independent of each others?

Comment: @Joey: You can only go by what the manufacturer of the part you are actually using says.  What other manufacturers say about parts with similar part numbers are at best only things to investigate.  In this case since there is doubt, I'd put the switches between the Ax inputs and ground, and add something like a 100 kOhm pullup to each one.  That should cover both cases.  The only downside is more current draw when a switch is closed.  If the extra uA don't matter, then you're done.

Answer (score 2):

There is no internal pull-up resistor. (Otherwise, I<sub>I</sub> in section 6.5 would be larger than for a plain CMOS input.)

The datasheet says:

> Connect directly to V<sub>CC</sub> or ground.
>   Pullup resistors are not needed.

This is to clarify that the A0/A1/A2 pins are *not* TTL inputs and therefore do not require external resistors to limit the input current.

However, this remark applies only to the described situation, when the pin is connected directly to one rail.
When you want to control the input with a switch, and do not have a SPDT switch, you do have to use a pull-up (or pull-down) resistor to ensure a valid voltage level.

Comment: In that case is the pull-down in the first circuit above correct?

Comment: ․․․․․․․․․․․Yes.